# PostgreSQL unnest, int4range with where clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I have a datatable called `mytable`:

```
╔════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════╗
║ id │ segments                     │ duration ║
╠════╪══════════════════════════════╪══════════╣
║ 1  │ {"[1,4)","[6,13)","[15,19)"} │ 14       ║
╟────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────╢
║ 2  │ {"[3,16)","[19,22)"}         │ 16       ║
╚════╧══════════════════════════════╧══════════╝
```

`segments` is an array of time intervals in seconds.
`duration` is the sum of the time intervals in `segments` in seconds.

For example, for `id`=1, the three intervals in `segments` are 3, 7, and 4 seconds, respectively. They total 14 seconds in `duration`.

I would like to pull from this table only the rows that fulfill both criteria:

- Have no individual `segments` that are not less than 10 seconds
- Have a `duration` that is at least 10 seconds

The query should only return `id`=1 because its individual `segments` each are less than 10 seconds AND its `duration` is at least 10 seconds.

The query should NOT return `id`=2 because one of its `segments` is 13 seconds in length. Its `duration` is at least 10 seconds, but it fails the first condition concerning `segments`.

Comment: Are you storing an array of strings, or a nested array of numbers? Your representation of the data is not clear to me.

Comment: Nested array of numbers. The data type is int4range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest the arrays in a lateral join and calculate sums in groups by `id`. Use the Boolean aggregate `bool_and()` to eliminate segments less than 10 seconds.

```
select id, segments, sum(elem.upper- elem.lower) as duration
from my_table
cross join unnest(segments) elem
group by id
having bool_and(elem.upper- elem.lower < 10)
and sum(elem.upper- elem.lower) >= 10
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ccdd81178cbd637f1841e6a2a79f82f)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lateral join:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join lateral (
    select bool_and(seg.upper - seg.lower < 10) to_keep
    from unnest(t.segments) seg 
) x on x.to_keep
where t.duration >+ 10
```

The subquery unnests the array and uses `bool_or()` to ensure that all intervals are less than 10 seconds; the join condition eliminates unwanted rows.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cd20f5bae3aa809b8327160218071216)**:

```
id | segments                     | duration
-: | :--------------------------- | -------:
 1 | {"[1,4)","[6,13)","[15,19)"} |       14
```